# How to put in extended ASCII-characters into textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, extended-ascii

I'm trying to create an autofill function. I'm using a select list, and based on option selected, some textboxes gets values put into them. The only problem is that I can't get extended ASCII-characters into a textbox with the function I'm using.

JS:

```
function fillContact() {
    var contact = document.getElementById('contact'),
        namebox = document.getElementById('namebox');

    if (contact.value === 'Bjorn') {
        namebox.value = 'Bj' + String.fromCharCode(148) + 'rn';
    }
    else if (contact.value === 'Tommy') {
        namebox.value = 'Tommy';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id='contact' onchange='fillContact();'>
   <option selected>-Choose contact-</option>
   <option value='Bjorn'>Bjorn</option>
   <option value='Tommy'>Tommy</option>
</select>

Name: <input type='textbox' id='namebox'>
```

String.fromCharCode() just doesn't encompass ASCII-character 148 (ö), that I want to put into a textbox. Any other String-function that can make it work? Something like String.getExtendedCharCode(148), or equivalent?

Note that other characters up to 128 works, and that contact 'Tommy' works.

Comment: The best option is to use UTF-8 instead of extended ASCII

Comment: JavaScript uses Unicode/UTF-16. Your question seems to be based on a misunderstanding of what ASCII means and what "extended ASCII" doesn't mean. Regardless, they aren't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
namebox.value = 'Bj' + "\xF6" + 'rn';
```